# Apply numpy index to matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have spent the last hour trying to figure this out

Suppose we have

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5, 20) - 0.5
amin_index = np.argmin(np.abs(a), axis=1)
print(amin_index)
> [ 0 12  5 18  1] # or something similar
```

this does not work:

```
a[amin_index]
```

So, in essence, I need to find the minima along a certain axis for the array np.abs(a), but then extract the values from the array a at these positions. How can I apply an index to just one axis?

Probably very simple, but I can't get it figured out. Also, I can't use any loops since I have to do this for arrays with several million entries.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to pass in the array of row indexes (e.g. `[0,1,2,3,4]`) and the list of column indexes for the minimum in each corresponding row (your list `amin_index`).

This returns an array containing the value at `[i, amin_index[i]]` for each row `i`:

```
>>> a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), amin_index]
array([-0.0069325 ,  0.04268358, -0.00128002, -0.01185333, -0.00389487])
```

This is basic indexing (rather than advanced indexing), so the returned array is actually a view of `a` rather than a new array in memory.

Comment: Thats it, thanks so much. I finally can go to sleep 

Answer (score 1):

Is because `argmin` returns indexes of columns for each of the rows (with `axis=1`), therefore you need to access to each row at those particular columns:

`a[range(a.shape[0]), amin_index]`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do `np.amin(np.abs(a), axis=1)`, it's much simpler **if** you don't need the intermediate `amin_index` array via argmin?

Numpy's [reference page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/) is an excellent resource, see "Indexing".

**Edits:** Timing is always useful:

```
In [3]: a=np.random.rand(4000, 4000)-.5

In [4]: %timeit np.amin(np.abs(a), axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 128 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), np.argmin(np.abs(a), axis=1)]
10 loops, best of 3: 135 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hey. I can't use that since I am not looking for the minima in the np.abs(a) array. I am only interested in these positions and then get the minima from a itself. ;)